# I tried editor.trigger('myapp','undo') but it's not working as expected

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor, undo, undo-redo, redo

I tried the below code for undo operation, but it's not working as i expected
**editor.trigger('whatever...','undo');**

This line is reverting the changes but word by word.

**For Example**: I have added the statement in the editor
"Create '112'"

This code is undoing 112, then space and then Create. But what I am expecting is whenever I click undo the last added line should be reverted (It should revert entire "Create '112'" line).

Is there any way to undo the last added line but not word by word in javascript.

It should revert the last added line.

It should undo the "Create '112'" line.

Comment: Post some code...